# Should we have smaller sized bounties?

Tags: discussion

Here on Linguistics stackexchange (not meta), we have very few users and even few interested ones, also the votes and replies to good questions are fewer than most of the other communities, also the questions die very frequently without an answer, having smaller bounties can be encouraging :)

Answer (score 5):

In fact, the amount of bounty is a result of a [long-running debate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbounty%5D+small) and compromise. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19980/) from 2009, for example.

I think, [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257518/) at Meta.SE and its answer(s) sums it up very well:

> If you did this, there would be no point of having bounties - because every user would start a bounty on their questions.

---

(I think, this thread from comments worth added into the answer)

The main concern of those who may want to see smaller sized bounties is that bounty can be "expensive" for a low-rep user. However, the expensiveness is always relative.

For instance, I noticed that on [travel.se], each my post receives more votes ([see, I'm not an active user](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26641/bytebuster) there, yet having 2k rep) . Hence, it is easier to earn reputation points, hence a user is easier to expend 50p for bounties.

So, in my opinion, **we should struggle for more voting per post**, rather than for lowering bounty limits.

Comment: But, don't you think, Linguistics SE is a bit underprivileged?

Comment: @WiccanKarnak, privileges are relative. For instance, I noticed that on [travel.se], each my post receives more votes ([see, I'm not an active user](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26641/bytebuster) there, yet having 2k rep) . Hence, it is easier to earn reputation points, hence a user is easier to expend 50p for bounties. So, in my opinion, we should struggle for more voting per post rather than for lowering bounty limits.

Comment: that makes perfect sense, but see my question on Ceq Wong here on Linguistics SE, it's so lowly received, even a single answer that was, was in comments and being on top% rep this month, I can't even risk a bounty!